# Change class of parent div based on attribute of label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If the `label` element contains 'false' is it possible to change the `class` of the parent `div`? And only from the one?

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-1" case="registered" id="school-1" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="true">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-2" case="registered" id="school-2" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="true">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-3" case="registered" id="school-3" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="false">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-4" case="registered" id="school-4" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="true">bla</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is. Have you attempted this? Where is your JS/JQ?

Comment: Yes.  (Though this is a misuse of the `for` attribute on the `label` element.)  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Is there only going to be one label with `false`?

Comment: The [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for) attribute should refer to an `id` of a form element.

Comment: If you want to adjust the styling you can also use the relative new [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector. `.myclass:has(label[for="false"]) {color: red}`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for your `false` value. (`for` is used specifically to associate a label with a corresponding form control element (like `input`.) I've used `data-check` here.

Then it depends whether one label will only ever be checked `false` or whether you might have *n* number of labels checked `false`.

##### One label checked false

```js
// Find the false label
const label = document.querySelector('.myclass label[data-check="false"]');

// Find the closest ancestor div and change the class
label.closest('div').className = 'newclass';
```

```css
.myclass {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.newclass {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-1" case="registered" id="school-1" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="true">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-2" case="registered" id="school-2" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="true">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-3" case="registered" id="school-3" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="false">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-4" case="registered" id="school-4" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="true">bla</label>
</div>
```

##### More than one label checked false

```js
// Select the divs
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');

// Iterate over them. If the corresponding label for a div
// has its check data attribute set to false change the class
// of the div
divs.forEach(div => {
  if (div.querySelector('label').dataset.check === 'false') {
    div.className = 'newclass';
  }
});
```

```css
.myclass {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.newclass {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-1" case="registered" id="school-1" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="false">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-2" case="registered" id="school-2" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="true">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-3" case="registered" id="school-3" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="false">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-4" case="registered" id="school-4" class="CheckBox">
  <label data-check="true">bla</label>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to achieve this using JavaScript. You can add an event listener to each checkbox, and when the checkbox is clicked, check the value of the associated label. If the value is "false," you can then change the class of the parent div.

```
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-1" case="registered" id="school-1" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="true">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-2" case="registered" id="school-2" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="true">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-3" case="registered" id="school-3" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="false">bla</label>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water-list" value="school-4" case="registered" id="school-4" class="CheckBox">
  <label for="true">bla</label>
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.CheckBox');

    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
      checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var label = this.parentElement.querySelector('label');
        var parentDiv = this.parentElement;

        if (label.getAttribute('for') === 'false') {
          parentDiv.classList.toggle('highlight');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: While I agree with what you've said, the thing about [SO] is that those asking the question typically want, expect, and require answers to include a *solution* to the problem, which most often requires a code example.

Comment: Understood. I appreciate the emphasis on practical solutions. I'll make sure to include code examples in my responses to better align with the expectations of the Stack Overflow community. Thank you for the feedback!